# On the two recent user bans

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, moderation, user-suspension

Why is one user banned for a year while the other only for 7 days?

Why is one user's recent post deleted by a mod as offensive and also warned in comments not to ask such anti-XYZ questions, but why hasn't the other user also been warned?

What steps are mods taking to ensure their actions are not biased?

To a lay user like myself it appears as if mods are handing out different punishments to different users for the same type of behavior.

It also gives the impression that if you belong to the same sect as one of the mods, you are given a longer rope.

Answer (score 10):

> Why is one user banned for a year while the other only for 7 days?

The duration of the ban is automatically chosen by the system while banning a user. It takes into consideration the previous history of the user. Moderators *can* override this, but usually they don't. It is an escalation. First warn, then 7 days, then 30 days, and then 365 days. Sometimes 1 year wouldn't be enough, and CMs go for more, say like 50 years:

[image]

> Why is one user's recent post deleted by a mod as offensive and also warned in comments not to ask such anti-XYZ questions, but why hasn't the other user also been warned?

The post deletion shows "offensive" because the post was flagged. If you can see that a mod has deleted the post, then it implies that the mod didn't flag it as offensive themselves, but instead a normal community user flagged it as offensive. Also, you mention about the user being warned in comments once before being suspended. That probably wasn't needed, but moderators are sometimes encouraged to warn users to be nice. Directly sending the mod message along with the suspension is usually the way to go.

> What steps are mods taking to ensure their actions are not biased?

The mods have ensured that their actions are not biased by suspending both users. Had they been biased, they would have looked away. Given that they have handled the flags cast by the community and then suspended both the users is ample proof that they are not biased.

> To a lay user like myself it appears as if mods are handing out different punishments to different users for the same type of behavior.

Yes, this is advocated by the system itself! Think about it like the fine for jumping a traffic signal. The first one is usually a small amount, but the third one would be a larger fine, and include suspension of driving license. The police aren't biased at all. In fact it is the public who need to make sure that they mend their ways.

> It also gives the impression that if you belong to the same sect as one of the mods, you are given a longer rope.

This reminds me about Alexander Pope's famous quote about how we see the world to be biased. Always assume good faith unless proven otherwise.

Comment: "Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days." says [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) blog post. You on the other hand claim "duration of the ban is automatically chosen by the system". Is the blog outdated? 'but moderators are sometimes encouraged to warn users to be nice' - ok, but why be nice with one user and not the other?

Comment: The duration of the ban _is_ chosen by the system. The moderators _can_ override it based on their discretion. As I said, moderators are _encouraged_ only, there is no hard rule that they need to warn the users. Also, it might be the case that two different moderators handled the two different users.

Comment: 'two different moderators handled the two different users' - so it need not be a collective decision? Do site mods present their case to CMs to ban users or are CMs not involved in this at all?

Comment: It needn't be a collective decision. CMs aren't involved in this at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: user are deaming offensive which they are opposed what is offensive who decide, now only the flaging user decide.. that is absolute wrong some valid points is offensive like I had comment which explained about why dhrama is not unreal what will happen its unreal according to tattva vada philosophy but that was flagged and deleted by user and moderate, that means in this Hinduism stack exchange is not about hindusim as whole its meant for one community of user right